# Change the Titles of ALL the Msgboxes for entire workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have created an Excel template that is being used by multiple people in my organization. I have a lot of msgboxes added in the code for error's or notifying the user. I constantly change the code based on new issue found and add more msgboxes. All these msgboxes have Title as "Microsoft Excel"

I know that we can change the title individually by adding the third argument to the [msgbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function) method. But what i'm looking for is to change the titles of **all the msgboxes** (Existing & New) to add a parameter (Username/Workbook Name) into the Title of the msgbox.

Comment: You could create your own function called `MsgBox` which takes the same parameters as the built-in function and just passes those parameters along to `VBA.MsgBox` along with your new title. Although this would update every MsgBox at once with no further code changes, it's still not a great idea. Take the time to fix the underlying issue instead

Comment: Maybe i didnt understand you correctly, but wouldn't adding a custom function called `msgbox` conflict with the existing `msgbox` method

Comment: @Gangula - My advice: Hands off from *overloading* existing functions or methods, even if you are distinguishing between `MsgBox()` and `VBA.MsgBox()` You'll run into issues shorter or later with such uncoordinated constructs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to alter the title parameter in every individual call to `MsgBox` then you can create a custom function called `MsgBox` to shadow the built-in function. The custom function just passes through all of its parameters to the built-in `MsgBox` function but it replaces the `title` parameter with a custom title instead.

```
Function MsgBox(prompt As String, Optional buttons As Long, Optional title As String, _
    Optional helpfile As String, Optional context As Long) As Integer

' Pass through the parameters to the built-in MsgBox function
' but replace the title with our own version
' Use the return value from the built-in function as our return value
MsgBox = VBA.MsgBox(prompt, buttons, "Custom Title", helpfile, context)

End Function
```

This works due to the concept of shadowing: if we don't fully qualify the name of the function we are trying to call, then a function with that name in a local scope would be called instead of a built-in function with the same name. We can still get to the built-in function if we fully qualify the name  - `VBA.MsgBox` - like this:

```
' Call the custom function
MsgBox "Hello world!"

' Call the built-in function
VBA.MsgBox "Hello world!"
```

I don't think that this answer is a particularly good solution to the problem. Changing all your calls to `MsgBox` to include the title parameter would definitely be preferable to creating a custom function like this

---

edit: we can make this slightly better by checking if a title was supplied to our function. To do this we can use the `IsMissing` function but this requires `title` to be a Variant instead of a String:

```
Function MsgBox(prompt As String, Optional buttons As Long, Optional title As Variant, _
    Optional helpfile As String, Optional context As Long) As Integer

' Pass through the parameters to the built-in MsgBox function
' Use the return value from the built-in function as our return value

If IsMissing(title) Then
    ' If no title has been supplied then use our custom title
    MsgBox = VBA.MsgBox(prompt, buttons, "Custom Title", helpfile, context)
Else
    ' Otherwise use the title supplied as a parameter
    MsgBox = VBA.MsgBox(prompt, buttons, title, helpfile, context)
End If

End Function
```

We can test that our new version is working correctly like this:

```
' Call the custom function
MsgBox "Hello world!"

' Call the custom function with a title
MsgBox "Hello world!", vbOKOnly, "My Title"

' Call the built-in function
VBA.MsgBox "Hello world!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next approach, please:

1. Create a `Public` variable name it, let us say, `msgTitle` in a standard module top side (in the declarations area):

```
    Public msgTitle as String
```

2. Initialize the variable in this way:
   In `Workbook_Open()` event:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        msgTitle = Application.UserName & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Name
    End Sub
```

2 bis: If for an unknown reason the variable looses its value, in some events (worksheet Change, SelectionChange etc.) the variable will be reinitialized in this way:

```
    If msgTitle = "" Then msgTitle = Application.UserName & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Name
```

3. Create all the necessary `MsgBox` in this way:

```
   MsgBox "Whatever necessary to be announced", vbCritical, msgTitle
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for a solution to change all msgbox title (Existing and New) at once.

Comment: @Gangula: Theoretically it is possible, I think I can do it, but it will take more to create such a procedure than putting such a variable in clipboard, searching in all workbook modules for `MsgBox` and replacing the title.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the msgbox title as a public variable, and you can use it throughout the project:

```
Public MsgBoxTitle As String

Sub InitialSub()

    MsgBoxTitle = Application.UserName & " - " & ThisWorkbook.Name
    AnotherSub

End Sub

Sub AnotherSub()

    MsgBox "This is a test!", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, MsgBoxTitle

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for a solution to change all msgbox title (Existing and New) at once.

Comment: To change existing titles I believe you will need to slog through your code with Find/Replace, but if you change the existing titles to your new public variable you will never have to do it again.